# Ошибка при запуске образа: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable

Tags: python-3.x, docker

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable

Проблема с запуском docker образа

В файле Dockerfile прописано:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim
RUN mkdir code
WORKDIR code
ADD . /code/
ADD .env.docker /code/.env
ENV APP_NAME=DJ_APP
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD gunicorn dj_prj.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

в файле .env.docker вынесен SECRET_KEY и DEBUG = True

но при запуске образа

docker run -p 7000:8000 django-docker

пишет ошибку: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Логичный вопрос — вот этот вот файл .env.docker вообще считывается хоть кем-нибудь?

Comment: добавьте в `docker run` опцию `--env-file=.env.docker`

Comment: не получается(
я запускаю вот так: docker run -p 7000:8000 django-docker

Comment: тогда возникает другая ошибка: 
poorly formatted environment: variable 'SECRET_KEY ' contains whitespaces.

Comment: Уберите пробелы вокруг = возможно?

Comment: да, убрала пробелы и "", но этого было недостаточно.
Помогло: docker run -d -e "SECRET_KEY= ...."  -e "DEBUG=True" -p 7000:8000 django-docker:1.0